# Best method to create short Unique IDs in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create unique IDs in MySQL for a php application. I what the IDs to be about 7 chars max, the only think i can think of doing is to used the uid that is created but i would like to create a random string rather than just 0000123 etc... i would prefer AB738DD or somthing of the like.

The other thing i thought of was using php to generate an id then check the db to see if it is already there, and if there isnt a match insert with that id, the only problem is i think that will create unneeded load on the mysql server and extra queries.

Has anyone else got any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be 7 character long? (Mysql has UUID() function that generates unique number for you, but it is a string representation of 128 bit number)

Comment: just a random idea. SUBSTRING(MD5(UUID()),0,7) -- in no way guarantees unique

Comment: Can you clarify what your real objection is to choosing the simplest solution? Unneeded complexity too often leads to tears.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the `time()` and then convert it to hex. It would give you like 8 chars.

```
dechex(time());
```

It will be unique, unless we go back in time, what would be awesome (not as much as go to the future, but still).

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store an integer but convert the value to hex on display. (Obviously this won't be random, but it wouldn't be all digits either).

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with the characters you want to permit. Then store an integer id but map it to a string modulo the length of your keys (scramble them if you want.) Start somewhere in the middle of the range if you prefer. Write a trivial pair of functions to convert one to the other and only expose the ugly one.

This way you can use the well-proven simple resource already provided for the purpose.